# R: Reduce Quality of PDF file in R

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I  have the following PDF file that I created:

```
library(pdftools)
library(magrittr)

# working directory
working_dir <- getwd()

# import
file_path1 <- paste0(working_dir, "/f1.pdf")
file_path2 <- paste0(working_dir, "/f2.pdf")

# Merge 
pdf_combine(c(file_path1, file_path2), output = paste0(working_dir, "/merged.pdf"))
```

**My Question:** Is it somehow possible to reduce the quality/size of the final PDF directly in R?

Thanks!

Comment: `pdf_combine()` is from the `qpdf` package, which also contains `pdf_compress()` - I think it's worth a go.  Also try `tools::compactPDF()`.

Comment: Are you maybe asking about the pdf _compression_ step that can be done at package build-time if the `qpdf` tool is installed?

Comment: thank you everyone! can someone please write an answer about this?

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I ended up using (it worked):

```
library(pdftools)
library(magrittr)

working_dir <- getwd()

# files 
file_path1 <- paste0(working_dir, "/file1.pdf")
file_path2 <- paste0(working_dir, "/file2.pdf")

# Merge 
pdf_combine(c(file_path1, file_path2), output = paste0(working_dir, "/merged.pdf"))
```